# How to Send user to two different web pages when login

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

```
protected static Boolean Authentication(string username, string password)
{
    string sqlstring;
    sqlstring = "Select Username, Password, UserType from Userprofile WHERE Username='" + username + "' and Password ='" + password + "'";

    // create a connection with sqldatabase 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
                 "Data Source=PRADEEP-LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BookStore;Integrated Security=True");

    // create a sql command which will user connection string and your select statement string
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstring, con);

    // create a sqldatabase reader which will execute the above command to get the values from sqldatabase
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader;

    // open a connection with sqldatabase
    con.Open();

    // execute sql command and store a return values in reade
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    // check if reader hase any value then return true otherwise return false
    if (reader.Read())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

Boolean blnresult;

blnresult = Authentication(Login2.UserName, Login2.Password);

if (blnresult == true)
{
    Session["User_ID"] = getIDFromName(Login2.UserName);
    Session["Check"] = true;
    Session["Username"] = Login2.UserName;

    Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
}
```

so a user like Staff or even Administrators loging to same Index.aspx. i want to change it to different web pages.

how to change sites for each user types. i have seperate user types. and i have taken UserType in the Authentication function.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.  Also, you should **NEVER** store passwords in plain text.

Comment: @SLaks: that isn't a vulnerability, it's a snazzy way of having "'' or ''='" as master password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make your authentication method return a string?  It can return the user type when a user is authenticated, and it can return empty or null when authentication fails.  Then you can just say

```
string userType = Authentication(Login2.UserName, Login2.Password);
if(userType != string.IsNullOrEmpty)
{
  if(userType.Equals("yourType")
    Response.Redirect("firstSite.aspx");
  elseif //...etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use [ASP.Net Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx).  A lot of this work as already been done for you in a much safer way.

[Using Forms Authentication in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150650/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110701-1.shtml)

[15 Seconds : Using Forms Authentication in ASP.NET - Part 1](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020220.htm)

Finally, check out the builtin in [ASP.Net Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) that can be used for logging in your users, displaying content based on user, password recovery, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Session["UserType"] == "admin")
    Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
else
    Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor `Authentication` into something else that returns user group or null for missing user for the provided credentials, then add switch or if-statements in the caller.